# Uso della locuzione "sotto forma di"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Ho trovato la locuzione preposizionale ["sotto forma di" nel dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sotto-forma-di), ma non sono sicura di saperla usare nel modo giusto. Ad esempio, sarebbe corretto adoperarla in questo modo?

> A volte succede che gli argomenti proposti dalle foto del giorno del National Geographic sono cose tanto lontane dalla mia vita quotidiana che mi è veramente molto difficile parlarne. Oggi posso scegliere tra il branco di elefanti di questa immagine, un gruppo di rinoceronti che va in fila per una strada sterrata oppure un gruppo di pesci che nuota nel fondo del mare, dei quali uno ha la bocca aperta. Neanche questi ultimi, **sotto forma di** "pesci morti adatti al consumo umano", sono veramente molto presenti nella mia vita: detesto il pesce e mio marito non ne può mangiare perché ne è allergico.

In questo scritto faccio riferimento a degli esercizi di italiano consistenti a fare una descrizione di una fotografia del National Geographic.

**Aggiornamento:** Ho trovato anche  questa [spiegazione della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_290.html).

Comment: Il significato è quello di porre un caso singolo nell'ambito di una tipologia (specie, genere, forma), magari una tipologia diversa da quella usuale nell'ambito della quale si pone in genere quel caso concreto: _Odio il dizionario con cui ho sudato sette camicie ma sotto forma di oggetto contundente con cui spaccare la testa  al prof ho incominciato ad apprezzarlo_

Comment: Viene direttamente dal latino “sub forma” (con il genitivo).

Comment: @mario: Nel mio esempio però il pesce si presenta in un aspetto solito: non è qualcosa di inusuale avere il pesce preparato per il consumo umano. In tale caso, la locuzione "sotto forma di" non sarebbe la più adatta?

Comment: @Charo, no, nel brano i pesci sono prima visti come bellezza naturalistica  (secondo lo stile dei documentari del Nat. Geo.) poi come cibo per umani. Il punto è lo spostamento di classificazione, e di relative associazioni mentali, rispetto alla presentazione del documentario.

Comment: @charo. Per qualche motivo la tua domanda _In tale caso, la locuzione "sotto forma di" non sarebbe la più adatta?_ mi suona il contrario di quello che credo tu voglia chiedere.

Comment: @mario: È un dubbio che ho avuto leggendo il tuo primo commento e anche la spiegazione e l'esempio della Treccani: *la dea si presentò sotto forma di civetta*.

Comment: @charo, qui però è letterale, la Dea si trasforma (almeno nell'aspetto esteriore, cioè nella forma) in civetta.

Comment: @charo, visti esempi Treccani. A parziale correzione del mio commento, quelli sono sicuramente gli usi corretti, in cui una stessa entità assume forme diverse. Nel testo proposto  si tratta piuttosto di essere concepito sotto concetti diversi (bellezza naturale vs. cibo),  il che può essere assimilato - con un qualche abuso dell'uso corretto - all'apparire con diversa forma.

Answer (score 2):

> A volte succede che gli argomenti proposti dalle foto del giorno del National Geographic sono cose tanto lontane dalla mia vita quotidiana che mi è veramente molto difficile parlarne. Oggi posso scegliere tra il branco di elefanti di questa immagine, un gruppo di rinoceronti che va in fila per una strada sterrata oppure un gruppo di pesci che nuota nel fondo del mare, ***uno dei quali*** ha la bocca aperta. Neanche questi ultimi, ***sotto forma di*** [image] "pesci morti adatti al consumo umano", sono veramente molto presenti nella mia vita: detesto il pesce e mio marito non ne può mangiare perché ne è allergico.

Suona meglio "Uno dei quali" ma ovviamente non è un errore!

"Sotto forma di" invece è corretta.

Viene molto utilizzata questa espressione!

***"Dissimulare insulti sotto forma di frasi innocue"***

***Era uno stranissimo animale! Il corpo bitorzoluto le gambe sottili e slanciate... Sembrava quasi un mostro leggendario sotto forma di gatto e con qualche leggero dettaglio da topo.***